# Then there exists $x\in \mathcal{X}\setminus\mathcal{M}$ and $\inf_{u\in \mathcal{M}}\Vert x-u\Vert>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be an infinite-dimensional normed vector space. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ is finite-dimensional and it is a proper closed subspace. Then there exists $x\in \mathcal{X}\setminus\mathcal{M}$ and $\inf_{u\in \mathcal{M}}\Vert x-u\Vert>0.$

> Question 1: Why we need to assume a proper closed subspace but not just a closed subspace.
>
> Question 2: How to prove the statement?

Comment: For the first question, i suppose that $X/X = 0$ hence there is only one element and the distance is always zero. Maybe you meant $X \setminus M$? In this case the difference is an empty set.

Comment: @piombino Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already assumed that $\mathcal X$ is infinite dimensional. So any finite dimensional subspace is necessarily a proper subspace. It is also known that any finite dimensional subspace is closed.

Now there is at least one element $x \in \mathcal X$ which is not in $\mathcal M$. Since $M$ is closed it follows that $d(x,\mathcal M) >0$. [Otherwise, there is a sequence $(x_n) $ in $\mathcal M$ such that $\|x-x_n\| \to 0$. Since $x_n \to x$  and $\mathcal M$ is closed we see that $x \in \mathcal M$ which is a contradiction]. Hence $d(x,\mathcal M)=\inf \{|x-y\|: y \in \mathcal M\}>0$.